# Bot framework SDK NodeJS and Custom Question Answering: Failed to generate answers: [object Object]

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

After an upgrade of one of my knowledgebases from QnaMaker to a language resource with custom question answering enable (FKA QnAMaker Managed), my chatbot does not function anymore and returns an error: DialogContextError: Failed to generate answers: [object Object]

My .env has:

```
QnAKnowledgebaseId=<name of my knowledgebase>
QnAEndpointKey=<the Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key from the prediction url
QnAEndpointHostName=https://<languageresourcename>.cognitiveservices.azure.com/  (I also tried to add language/ to the url)
```

QnaMaker initialization:

```
const { QnAMaker } = require('botbuilder-ai');
        try {
            this.qnaMaker = new QnAMaker({
                knowledgeBaseId: process.env.QnAKnowledgebaseId,
                endpointKey: process.env.QnAEndpointKey,
                host: process.env.QnAEndpointHostName
            });
        } catch (err) {
            console.warn(`QnAMaker Exception: ${ err } Check your QnAMaker configuration in .env`);
        }
```

And called by:

```
        const qnaResults = await this.qnaMaker.getAnswers(step.context);
```

dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
        "adaptivecards-templating": "^1.4.0",
        "applicationinsights": "^1.8.10",
        "azure-storage": "^2.10.5",
        "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
        "botbuilder": "^4.15.0",
        "botbuilder-ai": "^4.15.0",
        "botbuilder-azure-blobs": "4.14.1-preview",
        "botbuilder-dialogs": "^4.15.0",
        "botbuilder-lg": "^4.15.0",
        "botframework-config": "^4.11.2",
         ...
}
```

Using the key, knowledgebaseid and hostname from my old QnAMaker KB works just fine. Struggling to translate the new prediction url into an object for the QnAMaker.

**Update**
The class GenerateAnswerUtils (called by QnaMaker) is expecting the following:

```
const url = `${endpoint.host}/knowledgebases/${endpoint.knowledgeBaseId}/generateanswer`;
```

This will not work with a QnaMaker KB migrated to Custom Questions which expects an url like this:

```
'https://<languageresourcename>.cognitiveservices.azure.com/language/:query-knowledgebases?projectName=<projectname>&api-version=2021-10-01&deploymentName=production'
```

Not sure if this should be a bugreport or feature request. I will file an issue anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BotFramework SDK does not support the new Custom Questions feature yet. This was causing the error. A feature request is already filed.